# Independence afforded by using own domain for OpenID identifier

Tags: openid, openid-provider, identification

I'm looking at OpenID in general and also thinking of using it for a web app idea I have.

My question is about what can be done when an OpenID provider goes under, chooses to cancel your account, gets hacked, etc. (All theoretical to me at the moment, but I would like to have this clarified.)

If:

1) someone sets their domain to act as a delegate to the OpenID provider:

`<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server">`

`<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://username.myopenid.com/">`

or:

2) sets up [myOpenID for Domains](https://www.myopenid.com/product_domains) where either `member.yourdomain.com` or `openid.yourdomain.com/member` is used,

can they simply repoint their (sub)domain to another OpenID provider in the event of the ceasing of their original provider's service, meaning that sites at which they're registered with their OpenID (such as StackOverflow) will continue to identify them with their account once the update has propogated?